# Finding the percent of light absorbed by a sample

Tags: analytical-chemistry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I have an absorbance of $0.266$ and need to find the percent of light absorbed by the sample. Is it found by just turning it back into transmittence% and subtracting 1? So by that, would it be $(1 - 0.542)$ making the percent absorbed $45.8\%$?

Comment: Your calculation is correct. The percent absorbed is $45.8$%.

Comment: I wonder why have you needed confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

You need Beer-Lambert law

$$\frac{I}{I_0}=10^{-aLC}$$

where $I_0$ is initial intensity $I$ that transmitted by a sample of concentration $C$ with extinction coefficient $a$ in a cell of path length $L$. The ratio $I/I_0$ is called the transmittance and $\log_{10}(I_0/I)$ is called the absorbance or optical density (OD) which is  $aLC$.

As a rule of thumb an OD of $1$ corresponds to $10^{-1} \times 100 = 10\%$ transmittance, and OD of $2$ to $10^{-2} \times 100 = 1\%$ transmittance, etc.

(This law applies at each wavelength used, and assumes that the wavelength spread is tiny compared to the natural shape of a line in the spectrum)

The extinction coefficient is a measure of how strongly a molecule absorbs at *a given wavelength* and usually has units of $\pu{dm^3 mol-1 cm-1}$ if the cell length is in $\pu{cm}$ and concentration in $\pu{mol dm-3}$.

Comment: I made some edits to clear it for OP. That way, the percent transmission is clearly to be $10^{-0.266} \times 100 = 54.2\%$.